# Public final class R is already defined

Tags: java, android, sms

I have downloaded an android application from http://mobiforge.com/design-development/sms-messaging-android which sends and receives SMS.

Once I run the app in Eclipse, I got this error of "Public final class R is already defined". I have searched for the solution and I found one of the way is to remove R.java in the source file before importing it to Eclipse.

The problem has been solved but now whenever I run the app in my android phone, it crashes. As far as I know, there is no bug in the app. Could someone help me on this?

Link for the source code: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8hGK166N4U2RTBjV0Q4akIwVG8/edit

```
Log: W/InputEventReceiver(30305): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
E/ViewRootImpl(30305): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

Comment: Plug it in and give us the log

Comment: Phix, https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8hGK166N4U2RTBjV0Q4akIwVG8/edit

Comment: please update your question with the crash log which shows in your logcat

Comment: Phix & Sayem: "W/InputEventReceiver(30305): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
E/ViewRootImpl(30305): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null"

Is it this thing? I'm still new to android.

Answer (score 0):

remove the R.java file in the gen folder (Eclipse) and then clean the project. This will generate a new R.java file which should solve the problem.

Comment: Nikhil, W/InputEventReceiver(30305): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
E/ViewRootImpl(30305): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

Answer (score 0):

I know what's the problem now. It is actually the age of the app. There are few words that have been deprecated and I have changed them. Now the app works perfectly!